# ASP.NET MVC controller not receiving the parameter from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting null value for the actor(which is an action parameter). I tried all possible ways to call the action method. I don't know if there is any setting in the web.config or what. When I try it in sample MVC application, it worked fine(getting parameters as expected). But the same thing is not working in my current working project. Please help me.

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Time Info</th>
        <th>Actor</th>
        <th>Reset</th>
    </tr>
    @{
        List<LockedUser> lockedUsers = ViewBag.LockedUsers;
        foreach (LockedUser lockedUser in lockedUsers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@lockedUser.TimeInfo</td>
                <td>@lockedUser.Actor</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Reset", "Reset", "Admin", new { actor = "John" }, null)</td></tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Action in AdminController:

```
public ActionResult Reset(string actor)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(actor) != null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(actor);
                Debug.WriteLine("Reset Successfull");
                ViewBag.Message = "Reset Successfull";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Unable to reset";
            }
            return View();
        }
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{WCP}",
                defaults: new { controller = "EmailConfirm", action = "Index", WCP = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Reset", "Reset", "Admin", new { WCP= "John" }, null)</td></tr>
```

Comment: When I changed the parameter name to WCP, it worked fine. But, can you please tell me the possible reason for not receiving the actor parameter value?

Comment: it is because  WCP = UrlParameter.Optional in your startup.  If you  change it  to this actor= UrlParameter.Optiona then your actor will be working. The url doesn't contain a parameter name,  so you just need to point that it  should be  the value of your optional parameter.

Comment: I created a sample ASP.NET MVC project in visual studio. I had WCP = UrlParameter.Optional in my router config. I tried with actor as a parameter in the controller. It worked fine. Can you please tell me why the above code example is not working. I mean what could be the reason.